# Unable to revert changes to hosts file in OS X Lion

Tags: macos, mac, dns, hosts

I edited the hosts file and added:

`10.0.0.1  devsys.crossreader.net`

Later I commented out the entry:

`#10.0.0.1  devsys.crossreader.net`

When I ping or browse to devsys.crossreader.net the returning IP is still 10.0.0.1. I tried to flush the dnscache, and even rebooted but that didn't work. Why does this happens?

---

here is the entire hosts file

```
###############
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
#10.0.0.1 devsys.crossreader.net
```

Comment: this is my hosts file http://imgur.com/R0Xcl

And this is what happen when i ping to devsys.crossreader.net

http://imgur.com/JBA7u

Comment: What happens if you enter `host devsys.crossreader.net` in Terminal? What about `dig devsys.crossreader.net`?

Answer (score 1):

Since your `/etc/hosts` is not the problem, the logical conclusion is that your DNS server is responding with that IP address, or you aren't using the DNS server you expect. To verify this, paste this into **Terminal.app**:

```
host -a devsys.crossreader.net
```

[image: Terminal screenshot with results of above command]

Answer (score 0):

The hosts file deals with each entry as it comes. For example:

```
127.0.0.1 www.apple.com
#127.0.0.1 www.apple.com
```

Will point your computer to 127.0.0.1 when you connect to apple.com.

You will need to comment out the one single line to stop the redirect. For example:

```
#127.0.0.1 www.apple.com
```

Will point your computer to Apple's servers. After making the changes, you can run the following to clear out your DNS cache:

```
dscacheutil -flushcache
```

Comment: @chsum: If I read the question correctly, the line is commented out but still gets the wrong IP.

Comment: I got that too re-reading the question (and edited the original post to be clearer). I would actually like to see the entire hosts file and also the command he used to "clear" it.

Comment: this is my hosts file http://imgur.com/R0Xcl

Comment: @navotvolk I've verified adding and uncommenting entries in the hosts file. It works without a need to clear your DNS cache. Adding a comment should restore the default IP instantly (upon save). When you edit the file, you are using sudo (e.g., sudo nano /etc/hosts), correct? I can't see anything else that would interfere with it not working. Perhaps a good lesson to not mess with your network (or files in etc) unless you absolutely know what you are doing ;)

Comment: @cksum i did it a lot and everything went well. is there a chance that it stuck some where else in the DNS? i edit it with sudo etc/hosts and still no luck

Comment: `sudo /etc/hosts` I hope (the initial / is important!)

Comment: You did save it, right? What do you see when you do `cat /etc/hosts`?

Comment: @patrix yes i saved it. 
this is my screenshot when i do cat /etc/hosts http://imgur.com/hrkZd belive me guys it's strange i know my way around the hosts...